# AEM Add File: Exception occurred: This tree does not exist

Tags: java, file, aem, aem-6, crx

I am trying to create a txt file under `/conf` but got this error:

> Exception occurred: This tree does not exist

Here is the simplified version of my code - ignoring the file content:

```
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
Node confNode = session.getNode("/conf");
Node fileNode = confNode.addNode("helloworld.txt", "nt:file");
session.save();
```

Am I missing anything? `/conf` path exists in CRXDE so I am not sure why it says the tree does not exist. I have also make sure the SystemUser.yaml has the write and read permission under /conf